# ajax call occurs after ko binding is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am trying to pull data from a database using an ajax call and then put that data in a view model which will then be bound to a table using knockout.  Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var LoadFiles = '@Url.Action("Files", "Home")';

        var HomeModel = function () {
            debugger
            var self = this;
            self.rows = ko.observableArray([]);

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: LoadFiles,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('inside ajax call');
                    self.rows = JSON.parse(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('error');

                }
            });
        }

            alert('outside ajax call');
            var model = new HomeModel();
            debugger
            ko.applyBindings(model);
    });  
</script>    
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

However, the problem is that my view model.rows is empty because as I discovered through some alert("") calls, the  `alert('outside ajax call'); is called first, then the page loads and binding is applied, then the  alert('inside ajax call'); is called.  I don't understand how this is possible especially since I call var model = new HomeModel() before the bindings are applied.  How can I ensure that the self.rows of my HomeModel are populated before the page loads to ensure my .rows are not empty?

UPDATE:
Thanks to @RoyJ, this now works as expected:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var LoadFiles = '@Url.Action("Files", "Home")';

        var HomeModel = function () {
            debugger
            alert('above');
            var self = this;
            self.rows = ko.observableArray([]); 

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: LoadFiles,
                success: function (data) {

                    alert('inside ajax call');
                    self.rows(JSON.parse(data))
                    alert('below');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('error');

                }
            });
        }

            alert('outside ajax call');
            var model = new HomeModel();
            debugger
            ko.applyBindings(model);
    });


</script>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: You're overwriting your `self.rows` observable. Instead, do `self.rows(JSON.parse(data))`

Comment: @RoyJ thank you so much that worked.  I'll update my answer for anyone who might have the same problem.  So the ko binding is set BEFORE the .ajax call?  I would think it would be set at the ko.applyBindings point.

Comment: you can just self.rows(data).

Comment: This is not a question any more, as it includes part of the answer, although the part of "why the ajax call happens later" is still unanswered. Perhaps you should modify your question.